# Creating a Windows Store application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I am trying to make something like an Hello world application in C# just to test how does the Windows Store application development go.
I have an laptop running Windows 8 on which I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Professional. Since I am a student I got a free Developer Licence, but when I start Visual Studio I get a problem.
When I click on new project and choose a blank XAML application, it starts to create the project and than asks me for the developer licence, all that I can do is click on accept (which needs to be approved by the admin account of the computer). After that it is still Creating the project, but that step never stops. 
Is there a problem with Visual Studio or is there something wrong with the developer licence?

I don't get any error or something like that... it is just over half an hour in the "Creating project" step...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install a developer license on a machine, you will need elevated privileges (aka running as admin after a UAC prompt).
If you have admin rights in the machine and your VS is not installing license, try doing it from powershell by using the Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration commandlet..
You can read all about installing a developer license at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974578.aspx

Good luck!

Comment: THX for your answer
i have installed the developer licence successfully now :)
i have upgraded my RAM so that the project loading is not so slow anymore :)